# componentWillReceiveProps on react does not pass the current property when ever it triggers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello guys I'm new to react
I'm working with react component passing a property from a state of parent component and I'm not sure why i get an undefined property error whenever i trigger and event from the parent component

You can visit the code here@ [https://codepen.io/private_ryan/pen/RVBdpO?editors=0011#live-view](http:////codepen.io/private_ryan/pen/RVBdpO?editors=0011#live-view) show console and click the edit button

**SampleTable Component**

```
 constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { UPD:[] };
}

updateRow(x) {
    var array = this.state.TRs;
    var index = array.findIndex(e => e.id == x);
    this.setState({
        UPD: this.state.TRs[index]
    });
}

render() {
    return (<AddFormData onAdd={ this.onAddForm } 
               upd={ this.state.UPD } 
               updcan={ this.cancelUpd } 
               propUpd= { this.propcessUpd } />
             <button onClick={ this.updateRow} value={ some.id } >click me</button>
     );
}
```

**AddFormData Component**

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { textName: '', textArea: '' };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(){
    console.log( this.props ) // undefined no props when first click
    // set the state here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New props are received as parameters to the function:

`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: @RED please upvote and/or accept an answer when it solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillReceiveProps` will get called whenever you do any changes in props values in parent component, new values will get passed as parameter and after this lifecycle method `this.props` will get updated so if you do `console.log(this.props)` inside this it will log the previous value not the new one.

Use this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    console.log(this.props.upd.id, newProps)
}
```

Check the [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmBjQW?editors=0011).